# How can I config .proto path in Java GRPC?

Tags: java, grpc

[image]

As picture show above,my java project path is:

```
--stub-service
------src
--------main
----------java
----------proto
--------------helloworld.proto(1)
------stub-protocol
--------helloworld.proto(2)
```

and I want to generate target code by .proto file.
The grpc tutorials are to build a hello world.proto file in src/main/proto,
but my hello world.proto file in the sub-protocol.

How can I config .proto path in Java GRPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protobuf plugin allows for this, although it is recommended that you use the standard convention.

Doc link:
https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#configuring-protobuf-compilation

You can tell the proto plugin about your non standard proto dir by adding this to your build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir "${project.projectDir}/stub-protocol/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is great.